# Dynamically determine the iteration of a project - Rally SDK 1.33

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm working on writing and displaying Rally apps outside of Rally. Does anyone know of a way to dynamically determine the iteration of a project using Rally SDK 1.33? I currently have to supply the iteration key value in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by iteration of a project you mean the current iteration, you may use this query:

```
query: '((StartDate <= today) AND (EndDate >= today))'
```

in the query object:

```
var queryObject = {
    key: 'it',
    type: 'iteration',
    fetch: 'Name,ObjectID,Project,StartDate,EndDate',
    query: '((StartDate <= today) AND (EndDate >= today))'
};
```

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. The problem is I need to get the iterationKey value. I'm trying to display a standard report, which needs to know which iteration to use. However, it won't accept the result of this query in the "iterations:" field because it is expecting that integer iterationKey value (previously acquired from the URL).

Comment: Nevermind, just got it. I wasn't processing the results of the query correctly, ObjectID was what I was looking for all along. Thanks!